# Arrow notation: this.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

While implementing map i noticed that in arrow notation there is type error `this.forEach` is not a function while in case of using es5 function its running fine.

```js
Array.prototype.map = function(projectionFunction) {

 var results = [];

        //Array.foreach is also error

 this.forEach( (arrayItem) => {
  results.push(projectionFunction(arrayItem));
 });

 return results;
};

var res = [5,10,15].map((x) => { return x + 2; });
console.log(res);
```

**Not working**

```js
    Array.prototype.map = (projectionFunction) => {
    
     var results = [];
    
     this.forEach( (arrayItem) => {
      results.push(projectionFunction(arrayItem));
     });
    
     return results;
    };
    
    var res = [5,10,15].map((x) => { return x + 2; });
    console.log(res);
```

**Error**

```
this.forEach( (arrayItem) => {
         ^

TypeError: this.forEach is not a function
```

Comment: You cannot use arrow *functions* for *methods*.

Comment: @Bergi—well, you *can*, but don't expect *this* to be useful. ;-)

Comment: @Bergi answer have no explanation even if use Array.forEach instead this.forEach...

Comment: @owaishanif786 Have you read the answer to the canonical question? `forEach` has nothing to do with that (and there's no `Array.forEach` function, so that wouldn't work anyway).

Comment: @owaishanif786—arrow functions adopt the *this* of their containing scope. Since this appears to be global code, then in the arrow function *this* is the global object, not the object on which the method was called (it can't be set at all by the call, it's set lexically). It's all in the answer referenced by Bergi.